# Move socket.io implementation from android activity to Android-Architectural-Component repository, Is it allowed or is it a good idea?

Tags: mvvm, socket.io, android-livedata

I'm updating my code to MVVM implementation with the Android-Architectural-Component and I'm thinking if it is a good idea to also move my socket from the activity to the repository.